# django-allauth set username the same as email

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I have a sign up form which asks only for email and password. When a user signs up, django-allauth creates a username for that user by striping the "@email" suffix form the user's email address.

So for example, if a user signs up with "**some-user@example.com**" his username will be "***some-user***" and if another user signs up with "**some-user@gmail.com**" then his username will be "**some-userr**"

But what I want is the username and email of the users to have the same value.

So how can I configure django-allauth to set the usernames as the users emails without striping their suffixes?

And if possible, how can I do that without creating a custom user.

In my settings.py:

```
#########################
# AllAuth Configuration #
#########################
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 8
```

Comment: Why would you need the username to be same as the email. You can allow your user to sign up with the email address anyway.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do exactly what you want to do with a signal on User pre_save.

Your settings look ok, so if you add the following code in somewhere like for example `core.models.py` it will work as you need:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def update_username_from_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user_email = instance.email
    username = user_email[:30]
    n = 1
    while User.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk).filter(username=username).exists():
        n += 1
        username = user_email[:(29 - len(str(n)))] + '-' + str(n)
    instance.username = username
```

The reason I do it with a signal is that I want that every time User is saved, the username is updated. You could check if the e-mail has changed update the username only in that case.

Then I limit the username to the first 30 characters of email (default max lenght of username is 30 chars):

```
username = user_email[:30]
```

You could also change the max lenght of username, but in my case I prefered to use the default lenght.

Since I make this, it could happen that there are repeated usernames. To avoid repeated usernames, in case that the resulting username after limiting it to 30 characters already exists, I put -2, -3... at the end to make the username unique:

```
n = 1
while User.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk).filter(username=username).exists():
    n += 1
    username = user_email[:(29 - len(str(n)))] + '-' + str(n)
instance.username = username
```

I hope this solution helps you!

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! This is exactly what I want. Sorry that I can't upvote you. I don't have enough reputation yet. When I have I will vote.

Comment: Good to hear that it helped! :)

Answer (score 7):

## profiles.models.py (custom user model)

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class CustomSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def populate_user(self, request, sociallogin, data):
        user = super().populate_user(request, sociallogin, data)
        user.username = user.email
        return user
```

## settings.py

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "profiles.models.CustomSocialAccountAdapter"
```

Answer (score 0):

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD (default: `"username"`, alternatives: `"email"` or `"username_email"`)
Specifies the login method to use – whether the user logs in by entering their username, email address, or either one of both. Setting this to `"email"` requires `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True`

[Full configuration here](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/configuration.html)