# Use email to login in Django 1.11, I use cookiecutter-django with allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, cookiecutter-django

I started using cookiecutter-django because it seems so much advanced than just django-admin to start my project. So I created an eCommerce website and it requires only email to log in not the username.

So, I tried to follow the docs and changes my settings.py like this:

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:redirect'
LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'
```

Here is my accounts.User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a fullname")

        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name = full_name
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['full_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

There is default `users` dir which has its own models.py, views.py and urls.py but I have no knowledge to modify it.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^$',
        view=views.UserListView.as_view(),
        name='list'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^~redirect/$',
        view=views.UserRedirectView.as_view(),
        name='redirect'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        view=views.UserDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^~update/$',
        view=views.UserUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='update'
    ),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):

    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': self.username})
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, RedirectView, UpdateView

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from .models import User
from enrolments.models import Enrolment


class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'


class UserRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})


class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    fields = ['name', ]

    # we already imported User in the view code above, remember?
    model = User

    # send the user back to their own page after a successful update
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):
        # Only get the User record for the user making the request
        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)


class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

Here is the error when I sign in, although it let me sign in when I go to the homepage. but when I click 'Sign In' button it prompts me with this error. Please guide me through it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

As of now (June 2020) there is an easier way to do this with Django Cookie cutter.

Firstly in the Django settings `config/settings/base.py` we need to adjust the AllAuth settings so that firstly the email is used as the primary identifier and not username, and secondly so that the username field is hidden in the SignUp page

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
```

The Django AllAuth documentation of this can be found [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=settings#configuration)

Then in the User model, we add a signal that will fire whenever the user instance is updated and copy the email address over to the username field.  This way they stay in sync.  The while loop just deals with the situation if there are conflicting email addresses (which their should not be):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def update_username_from_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user_email = instance.email
    username = user_email[:130]
    n = 1
    while User.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk).filter(username=username).exists():
        n += 1
        username = user_email[: (129 - len(str(n)))] + "-" + str(n)
    instance.username = username
```

This user model update was proposed by @ferrangb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348705/django-allauth-set-username-the-same-as-email)

Comment: This is very neat! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: This is still valid for Django 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to figure out the way.
Here is my new models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, full_name, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a fullname")

        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name = full_name,
            username = new_username
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, username, email, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user




class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['full_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Here is my views.py file in 'users' dir:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, RedirectView, UpdateView

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from accounts.models import User
from enrolments.models import Enrolment


class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'


class UserRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})


class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    fields = ['full_name', ]

    # we already imported User in the view code above, remember?
    model = User

    # send the user back to their own page after a successful update
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):
        # Only get the User record for the user making the request
        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)


class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    # These next two lines tell the view to index lookups by username
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

and my settings.py file:

```
# ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:redirect'
LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'
```

Although, I need to have username while signing up only but after that, it just works. I don't need to change any other files.
I hope this helps.
Thanks.